# Linked-List file input, cant stop with EOF

Tags: c

I want to read from a file with `./sample < input.txt` command but it does not stop with EOF.
I need to ctrl+c to determine that it is EOF.
So how can I read more than one line?
I need to put it into the main loop which can determine EOF without ctrl+c.
As I planned, there must be 2 loops:
Main loop: to get other lines from file, Insert new node to fill up condition should be "EOF".
Sub loop: to fill up character array by characters, condition should be "\n".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 80


struct node {
  char str[SIZE];
  struct node* next;
};

void read_line(struct node* line_list);

int main(void)
{

    struct node* line_list = NULL; // linked list - headp

    read_line(line_list);

    return 0;
}

void read_line(struct node* line_list)
 {
    int ch, i = 0;

    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(temp!=NULL) {
      while((ch = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (ch != '\n')
        {
          temp->str[i] = '\0';
          //insert(&line_list,temp.str);
          break;
        }   
        if (i < SIZE) 
          temp->str[i++] = ch;
        printf("New str: %s\n",temp->str);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you debugged the code what is the value of ch when the EOF was reached?

Comment: Actually, i really do not know how to debug :( I work on cygwin. If you tell me i can try to debug it.

Comment: @user1289547 Are you sure the first character in your input file is not a newline? Please show your sample input file contents.

Comment: Alan Turing
Ahme Mala
Doezi Moze

Comment: it does not start with new line char and there's "enter" between them.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) { // now you have your valid ch
  if (ch == '\n') break; // end-of-line is a quitter
}
```

EDITH says: abtract versus concret.
Okay, i go back one step and write your code in pseudocode

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
  // this is a foreverloop until you hit end of file

  // now comes the state machine
  if (ch != NEWLINE) {
    // collect the string
    string.add(ch); // pseudocode
  } else {
    // do some accountings with the collected string
    list.add(string); // pseudocode
    string.print();
  }
}
```

Comment: it does not even read the file now. As I can not see any print after running the program.

Comment: @user1289547 Edit your question to show how you have upated your code.

Comment: I need 2 loops, first, check for EOF and the second is start reading other lines after newline character. Because I'm trying to create linked list with nodes filled up by lines.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Ignore my original post, I am not thinking right on a Friday night. Your `while` loop test had a different problem as pointed out by Peter. However, you still need to check `temp != NULL` after the `malloc`.

Comment: while(ch != EOF){
 while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' ){
  if (i < SIZE) 
  temp->str[i++] = ch;
 }
  temp->str[i] = '\0';
 printf("New str: %s\n",temp->str);}
The problem is i need a main loop, When i do write them both in same condition i can only generate 1 string, i may need to full an array

Comment: @user1289547 I can't seem to understand what you mean by "main loop". Please edit your question to explain what your problem is. In any case, to test for both newline and `EOF` using a logical AND does not make sense. Also, you need to do: `if (temp != NULL) { ... while ... }`. You need to make sure that `malloc` was successful before you dereference `temp`.

Comment: I edited. You may understand what i want to do, with "//insert(line_list)". I want to get lines as characters and store them in to a linked list. My code gets first line successfully but it does not stop w/o ctrl+C command.

Comment: your edit is "silly", because "while (ch)" starts with an un-initialised "ch". it should be more like "while ((ch = getch()) != EOF)" and no while in a while.

Comment: @Peter Miehle my while condition is same as yours? i'm confused about the situation that where shall i write the break? I need 2 while, one of them is to read characters until "\n" to get another empty node to fill. One of them is for "EOF" to read all the line. Am i wrong on this logic?

Comment: look at my edith in my post... The "break;" was not part of the solution. You had a "while (ch) getch();" construct that was false. I wanted to point you in the direction: "while (ch = getch()) test_and_process(ch);"